# Submit a Form Using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmdodbkp/2/) And Code:

```js
$("form.signupform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
  $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
  $(.result).html(data.result + " Watchlist");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="result"></p>
<form class="signupform" method="post" action="admin/signupinsert.php" onsubmit="this.onsubmit=function(){return false;}">

    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
   <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>

</form>
```

`admin/signupinsert.php` code:

```
// Insert into DB code in PHP

$response = new \stdClass();
$response->result = "".$result."";
die(json_encode($response));
```

I am trying to submit this form using My Jquery Ajax Code. And the signupinsert.php file will return a value in $result variable. I am trying to print it inside `<p class="result"></p>`

But, the code re-directs users to signupinsert.php page.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must prevent the default action of submitting the form

```
$("form.signupform").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // <-- add this

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
```

also, in your php file return proper `JSON` and avoid parsing the response in javascript with `JSON.parse(data);`

the output in your php file should look like this

```
$response = new \stdClass();
$response->result = $result;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($response);
```

and in your `success` handler just process the `data` parameter as a normal `json` object

```
$.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    $(.result).html(data.result + " Watchlist");
}
```

Also, just a curiosity, what is this supposed to do?

```
$response->result = "".$result."";
```

**Update:**
I just realized why you had most of the issues:

```
$('.result').html(data.result + " Watchlist");
  ^       ^
```

see the missing quotes

Comment: Here is my updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/pmdodbkp/3/

But sir, It still re-direct me to signupinsert.php page

Comment: `$response->result = "".$result."";` In my signupinsert.php file, I give some values to $result, which I want the user to see. So i am sending them back to the main page

Comment: I was using the same code in my other website (insert movies to watchlist using ajax), and it is working perfectly fine. But don't know, what's wrong here.

Comment: I mean the quotes before and after `$result`

Comment: Another question would be why the `onsubmit` attribute... I would still understand if it was something like `onsubmit="executeHandler(); return false;"`

Comment: You can also write the same thing like `$response->result = $result.`

But if you want to add some text with $result variable, you just quote. Like` "Added to ".$result."  "`;

the quotes: `". ."` tells the server, that to take `$result` as a variable, not as a text.

Not good in explaining, I hope u understood

Comment: Guys, take a look at this code: It is working, but not mine, why? https://jsfiddle.net/pmdodbkp/5/

Comment: Oh, the main problem is with this line `    $ $(form).children(.result).html(data.result + " Watchlist");`..But what's wrong here?

Comment: hey @Toby see my last edit, also you don't need the `onsubmit` parameter in the form definition

Answer (score 0):

you are redirecting because of action:

```
action="admin/signupinsert.php"
var url = $(this).attr("action");
```

got me?

Comment: Not really. It is still supposed to work, I guess. Can you edit the fiddle and edit your answer please?

Comment: Please $.ajax instead of $.post

Comment: Same result bro

Comment: remove action from form and add that into url variable
var url = "admin/signupinsert.php";

Comment: This just stop the page re-directing to signupinsert.php....Now it does not even run the code + it reloads the current form page bro